# Fatal error “LNK1104: cannot open file 'libCbc.lib'” when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, path, visual-studio-2017

I've never used VS before.
My friend shared with me his program working and running correctly (she uses VS 2013 and I use 2017 - any compatibility problem?).
I've downloaded it and changed the paths on

```
Configuration Properties, C and C++, General, Additional Include Directories (picture below)
Configuration Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories
```

However Im getting one fatal error which does not find this file located in:

```
Users\Julio\Documents\CPFL\SolverCPP\coin\libdebug

Users\Julio\Documents\CPFL\SolverCPP\coin\lib
```

How can I solve this path error? Also any tip to share project is welcome,

[image: ERROR MSG]
[image: PATH]

[image: PATH]

Comment: None of the 1100 existing posts with this same error message helped you?

Comment: Ive searched for the same king of issue and saw some answers but none solved...

Comment: Look very closely at the "additional library directories". Does any of them contain your .lib file?

Comment: `SolverCPP.tlog` - ?? Um. is that even a *directory* ?

Comment: Visual Studio will not search in subdirectories. The `.lib` file must be in one of the folders you told it to look.

Comment: Ive checked Additional Dpendencies and saw that: libCbc.lib was the first lib in there

Comment: I would expect it is in neither of the folders in your picture. The second does not even look like a folder (looks more like a visual studio log file). Didn't you say it was in ***Users\Julio\Documents\CPFL\SolverCPP\coin\lib***  Which is not listed in your picture. Looks like you have ***Users\Julio\Documents\CPFL\SolverCPP\coin*** but not ***Users\Julio\Documents\CPFL\SolverCPP\coin\lib***